# Error due to invalid combination of Toast and OnSensor Changed

Tags: toast, android-toast

In this the error being displayed is mentioned below. I have searched online for the right answer none is applicable so far. I am trying to toast a simple message upon detecting a sudden change in the accelerometer readings so as to detect a fall. I don't think there is any other mistake in the code, if there is you are most welcome to rectify it.

```
Error: cannot find symbol method maketext(MainActivity,String,int)
```

This is my Code:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (started) {
        double x = event.values[0];
        double y = event.values[1];
        double z = event.values[2];
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Data data = new Data(timestamp, x, y, z);
        sensorData.add(data);
    }

    if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        double gacc=SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY;
        double a=event.values[0];
        double b=event.values[1];
        double c=event.values[2];
        long mintime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean min = false;
        boolean max = false;
        int m = 0;
        double xyz=Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a,2)+Math.pow(b,2)+Math.pow(c,2)));

        if(xyz<=3.0){
            min = true;
        }
        if(min==true){
            m++;
            if(xyz>=14){
                max=true;
            }
        }
        if(min && max==true){
            Toast.maketext(MainActivity.this,"FALL DETECTED!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            m=0;
            min=false;
            max=false;
        }
        if (m>4) {
            m=0;
            min=false;
            max=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `maketext` instead of `makeText`. Note that camelCase.

Replace with:

```
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"FALL DETECTED!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

After you correct it, make sure that you are using the `android.widget.Toast`.

Comment: How did I miss that ??! But thanks anyway Laurentiu L., much appreciate it !